# Tastypie custom url to logged in user account

Tags: tastypie

I have a resource for custom users model in django 1.5 in my project and everything works great with tastypie (*/api/v1/users, /api/v1/users/1* ... )

I'd would like to create a customu url just to work with logged in user account. 
So for example if user with id=1 is logged in instead of */api/v1/users/1* link I'd would like to have */api/v1/users/loggedin* link that always points to logged in user (request.user) account.

What is the best way to do it ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom url and function in your user resource. The example code below is untested, but shouldh

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^users/loggedin/$",
            self.wrap_view('get_auth_user'), name="api_get_auth_user")
    ]

def get_search(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['get'])
    self.is_authenticated(request)
    self.is_authorized(request)
    self.throttle_check(request)

    auth_user = request.user.is_authenticated() ? {} : this.obj_get(request, pk=request.user.id)                             

    self.log_throttled_access(request)
    return self.create_response(request, auth_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes adding custom actions to models a lot easier.
https://github.com/thelonecabbage/django-tastypie-actions

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.